# Remove rows with duplicate values in a specific column of a CSV file

Tags: php, csv, file, filter

I have data.csv here:

```
id: 10, location: Canada, people: 12
id: 10, location: United States, people: 15
id: 15, location: England, people: 19
id: 16, location: India, people: 20
id: 16, location: Germany, people: 9
```

I want it to output using PHP:

```
id: 10, location: Canada, people: 12
id: 15, location: England, people: 19
id: 16, location: India, people: 20
```

by deleting rows that have the same value in the first column.
How can I do this? (I'm new to PHP and don't really know what to do here; I tried some scripts others have made for similar problems but they don't seem to work) I would preferably want it to echo out the result rather than overwriting or creating a new file.

Comment: Do you know how to parse a CSV file into an array? Also, why would you have an identical ID for a row with otherwise totally different data?

Comment: No, I don't know much about php and I would like to keep the csv format. This is just an example, I just want ones with identical ids removed.

Comment: How do you know which one you want to keep? Why Canada and not United states? Always first is kept?

Comment: I just want to keep the first one.

Comment: In csv, the first row contains the headings, and the rest of the rows contain just the values or is it stored in exact same manner as you wrote in the post?

Comment: It's stored exactly like that, I just want to check the first row for duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read csv line by line with fgetcsv and create array where whatever is behind ':' is the key and whatever is after is a value.

Then you can remove duplicates.

When you have only the data you need construct csv string. You can just use it or store it in output csv file.

```
<?php

$handle = fopen("data.csv", "r");

// parse csv line by line and create data array with its information
$data = [];
while (($row = fgetcsv($handle)) !== false) {
  $newRow = [];
  foreach ($row as $field) {
     $parts = explode(':', $field);
     $key = trim($parts[0]);
     $value = trim($parts[1]);

     $newRow[$key] = $value;
  }

  $data[] = $newRow;
}

// iterate data and remove duplicate ids - keep only first id occurence
$indexedData = [];
foreach ($data as $row) {
  if (!isset($indexedData[$row['id']])) {
    $indexedData[$row['id']] = $row;
  }
}

var_dump($indexedData);

// create csv string with new data
$result = '';
foreach ($indexedData as $row) {
  $fields = [];
  foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
    $fields[] = $key.': '.$value;
  }
  $result .= implode(', ', $fields).PHP_EOL;
}

var_dump($result);
```

$indexedData:

```
array(3) {
  [10]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "10"
    ["location"]=>
    string(6) "Canada"
    ["people"]=>
    string(2) "12"
  }
  [15]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "15"
    ["location"]=>
    string(7) "England"
    ["people"]=>
    string(2) "19"
  }
  [16]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "16"
    ["location"]=>
    string(5) "India"
    ["people"]=>
    string(2) "20"
  }
}
```

$result:

```
string(111) "id: 10, location: Canada, people: 12
id: 15, location: England, people: 19
id: 16, location: India, people: 20
"
```

OR if you dont care about the data in the csv (for example you dont need people count etc.) here is simpler version:

```
<?php

$handle = fopen("data.csv", "r");

$data = [];
while (($row = fgetcsv($handle)) !== false) {
  if (!isset($data[$row[0]])) {
    $data[$row[0]] = $row;
  }
}

$result = '';
foreach ($data as $row) {
  $result .= implode(',', $row).PHP_EOL;
}

var_dump($result);
```

$result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need to parse the full lines of data.  A single `preg_replace()` call can delete the later occurring duplicate lines.

The following pattern is only built to process duplicates lines that are next to each other.  It is not built to handle duplicates separated by non-duplicates.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/JjMF4))

```
echo preg_replace(
         '/(^id: (\d+),.+)(?:\Rid: \2,.+)+/m',
         '$1',
         file_get_contents('data.csv')
     );
```

---

Alternatively, you can use a single loop and maintain a lookup array to determine whether an id has been echoed before.

This will work even if duplicate line are separated by non-duplicate lines.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/A3kl5))

```
foreach (explode(PHP_EOL, $csv) as $line) {
    $firstColumn = strtok($line, ',');
    if (!isset($lookup[$firstColumn])) {
        echo $line . PHP_EOL;
        $lookup[$firstColumn] = true;
    }
}
```